# Google perftool cannot read file "libprofiler.so.0"

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, google-perftools

I am trying the google performance tool for CPU time profiling. However, I had encountered some problem that I cannot read the shared library file "libprofiler.so.0"

I had read the README of google performace tool, there are 3 steps in the manual:

1. Compile my program with `-lprofiler`. I had done this part without any problem.
2. Run the binary of my program to generate a profile result file. 
   I failed in this step. When I try to run my binary, there is an error message: 
   `"error while loading shared libraries: libprofiler.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory."`.
   I googled, in this [page](http://apt.rikers.org/%23asterisk/20050421.html.gz), someone says the `"libprofiler.so.0"` is at `"/usr/local/lib"`, so I copied the share library file to the directory with my binary, and tried to run my binary. It still report the same error message.

I had just used Linux for about one year, please forgive me if my question is very stupid. And, thank you in advance.

My machine information:

- OS: Ubuntu 8.10
- Compiler: gcc 4.3.2
- shell: bash
- google performance tool version: 1.4 (I had download it just today)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Where is your `libprofiler.so.0`?

It should be installed into `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib`. Copying it to the same directory where your binary resides is useless (as you've already discovered).

EDIT: Apparently `libprofiler.so.0` *is* installed in /usr/local/lib. You probably should just run `/sbin/ldconfig` (as root) to update loader shared library cache. Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should not be necessary (unless you have very non-standard `glibc` installation).

Comment: The `libprofiler.so.0` is just at the `/usr/local/lib`, should I set any environment variable? like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Oh! God! I success! It is the environment variable problem! Thanks for all who read and answer my question!

Comment: Of in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` for 64 bit systems.